# error recognizing an @+id using fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to work through an example in an Android programming book (it's example 2 so i don't have a lot of debugging experience) but i am trying to create an Edit text with @+id/crime_title.
my issue is when i plug that into the onCreateView method, it doesn't see the id. In the findViewByID i an error that R.id.crime_title cannot be resolved or is not a field. what am i doing wrong? I'm sure it is something simple, but i just can't see what I'm doing wrong from the example.

Edit: I looked in the R.java file, and it the crime_title is not listed under id. is there a way to get it there? (the file says not to change anything in it manually).

Edit: I have done a clean and rebuild to get the id into the R.java file. but now i am getting an error that the variable R cannot be resolved. is there something i need to import or am missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/crime_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/crime_title_hint" />


</LinearLayout>
```

in my java file:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, parent, false);

    mTitleField = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
    mTitleField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence c, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            mCrime.setTitle(c.toString());
        }

    });
```

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt the project? Since you said it's not in R.java, this could be a longshot fix.

Comment: Im pretty new to this, i did a clean and build all, and the error went away for the crime_title, but i got the same error under the R in R.id.crime_title. is there an import i should have?

Comment: No, see my answer (in a sec when I post it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looking at some code I wrote a while back, it seems you need to be using ViewGroup instead of View.

```
ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crime, null);
```

Try that, the rest of the code shouldn't be affected.

Answer (score 2):

```
mTitleField = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.crime_title);
```

Try that :)

Comment: I still get the same error. i think it is because the crime_title isn't in the R.java file... maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I, try this!, 
mTitleField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.crime_title) without the "v." if that doesn't work check if you changed the name of the id title in a wrong way. hope to help!!

Comment: He is using a fragment.. He cannot do that!!..That is a wrong answer

Comment: o youre right, I didn't notice the fragment let me check!  thanks

Comment: The `v` is required because it's `onCreateView()` as opposed to `onCreate()`. You solution would work with the latter, but not this.

Comment: He is using onCreateView..what do you mean you didn't notice.!!